# Create a JS component from remote call

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails5 app I have the JS component below.

```
class IdentityConfirmation
  constructor: (item) ->
    ...
    @setEvents()

  setEvents: ->
    ...
```

I create the components when Turbolinks loads as such

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $.map $("[data-behavior~='identity-confirmation']"), (item, i) ->
    new IdentityConfirmation(item)
```

And everything works just fine.

Now I need to create a component from within a `js.erb` file.

My js.erb file looks like

```
$("#mydiv").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'mypartial' %>"); 
$.map($("[data-behavior~='identity-confirmation']"), function(item, i) {
  return new IdentityConfirmation(item);
});
```

And `mypartial` contains a div with data behavior equal to identity-confirmation.

However, the component is not created.

Am I missing anything here?

Thanks

Comment: Do you see any error when the partial is rendered, in rails server logs?

Comment: No, no error is displayed neither in the Rails console nor in the Browser console.

Comment: Does your rails console say that js.erb is rendered?

Comment: Yes the partial is rendered (I can see it on the screen). FYI, If I try to run some JS after `$.map`, (i.e. `console.log('test')`) the JS is not executed.

Comment: Try loading the constructor in the js.erb file itself. I think that's why it is not working.

Comment: What do you mean for `loading the constructor`?

Comment: I think IdentityConfirmation is not working in the js.erb file as you pointed out that **console.log** function is not printing anything to the console. Can you temporarily move the `$.map` function in the same partial which you are rendering inside `js.erb` file?

Comment: If I move it, it works but it is not what I want. I mean I don't want to have JS in the view

Comment: Where have you defined this `class IdentityConfirmation` function? It seems js.erb file cannot access it and that is why js code does not work.

Comment: You can check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5188948/3863146).